# Property of a spanning list in a finite-dimensional vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Suppose $ V $ is a finite-dimensional vector space and the list $ (w_{1}, w_{2}, ..., w_{n}) $ spans $ V $. Let $ u_{1} \in V $, prove that the list $ (u_{1}, w_{1}, w_{2}, ..., w_{n}) $ is linearly dependent.

This is one of the property in Axler's book "Linear Algebra Done Right" where he gives the claim but leaves no proof and I'm still stuck on it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried? Hint: Think about what it means for $(w_1,...,w_n)$ to span $V$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $w_1,\dots,w_n$ span $V$ and $u_1\in V$ then it follows we can write $u_1$ as a linear combination of $w_i$: $$u_1=\sum_{i=1}^n c_i w_i$$ for some coefficients $c_i$. It follows that $$u_1-\sum_{i=1}^n c_i w_i=0$$ What does this tell us about the linear dependence of $u_1,w_1,\dots,w_n$?

Comment: I see what you mean. Since the coefficient of $ u_{1} $ is $ 1 $ and the vector $ 0 $ is written as $ \displaystyle u_{1} - \sum_{i = 1}^n c_{i}w_{i} $, it follows that the list $ (u_{1}, w_{1}, \dots , w_{n}) $ is linearly dependent.